# Docky problem on reboot

Tags: unity, 18.04, dock, docky

I recently started using the Docky dock with Ubuntu 18.04. I like it, but I have an issue where whenever I restart my computer, anything I pinned to the dock disappears and has to be re-added after the reboot. I've Googled around for this issue, and it seems other people have it, but nobody seems to have an actual solution. Is there anything you have to do to "save" your configuration before rebooting? Any help is appreciated!